# Can you initialise a pointer variable with Golang reflect?

Tags: go

Suppose

```
type A struct {
   A1 int
}
var a *A
```

can we initialise "a" with reflect? reflect.ValueOf(a).Type().Elem() gives the type but it seems reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem() is the zero Value and not addressable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get addressable value for variable `a`:

```
var a *A
va := reflect.ValueOf(&a).Elem()
```

Allocate a new `A`:

```
v := reflect.New(va.Type().Elem())
```

Assign the pointer to newly allocated `A` to the variable `a`:

```
va.Set(v)
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/mFdvf95_BX)

Because Go passes arguments by value, it is not possible to set a value to `a` starting with `relfect.ValueOf(a)`.

Comment: How can that work when passing a rather than &a? In that case I can't see how you can set a new value to a.

Comment: It is not possible to set a value `a` using `reflect.ValueOf(a)`.